# How to use mmap to point to STL type?

Tags: c++, stl, mmap

I have a mmap typecast to a char pointer

char *ptr;

ptr = (char *)mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

This was my earlier code. But now I want to use a map instead of char * as the requirements changed.

Now, my map is declared as
map < int, string > i_s_map;

How do I change my mmap call to point to the map?

Comment: mmap is defined in <sys/mman.h>. What is i_s_map? It's tagged STL. I don't see any reference to it. What do you want to do here?

Comment: Are you implying that `std::map` has something to do with `mmap`? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I know that mmap returns a void * pointer. I just want to know how I can typecast this void * pointer to point to one of the STL types.. in this case it's a map. It could be a list, set or multimap. I just want to know if this is possible.

Comment: Attempting to cast from one to the other would imply some kind of relationship between them. They are completely unrelated. (You can construct anything within the memory returned by `mmap`, though.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to store STL containers in shared memory, at least not share them. The reason is that they rely heavily on heap allocation, so out-of-the-box `std::map` will hold pointers from virtual address space of a different process.

Take a look at [`boost::interprocess`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) for a way to deal with this situation in C++.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a map object in the memory returned by mmap use placement new.

```
map<int,string> *i_s_map = new(ptr) map<int,string>();
```

That will create the map object itself in the memory.  In order to get the elements inside the map into the memory, you will need to create a custom allocator to keep the data in the memory.  You can use the boost interprocess library for some allocators which work inside shared memory.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.allocator_introduction