# Backup scheme for non-volatile C++ map constructs

Tags: c++, database, stl, dictionary, backup

I frequently use std::map or tr1::hashed_maps in my C++ code. I have an upcoming project where I would normally default to using such constructs, however in this project I have the requirement that such maps be non-volatile. I.e. upon application termination (both safely closed or accidentally killed, such as a power cut), the map data should be safely stored on disk, and restored upon subsequent application execution. Note this is no requirement that every bit of data up until the power-cut was stored, just all up to say a few seconds before.

The requirements are still that the application must be high performance, in terms of both accesses and stores to the maps. Obviously "high performance" is subjective, but there will be millions of loads/stores into the map per second.

This leads me to "guess" that I should use an SQL database, however I am inexperienced with databases, and worry that there will be considerable performance degredation moving from simple C++ containers to a full SQL infrastructure. Will SQL "cache" results in such as a way as to mitigate the performance effect?

Alternatively, a simple answer might be just to frequently (say every 10-30 seconds), write (serialize) a copy of the maps to disk. Depending on the size of the maps, which will be large (at least millions of entries), this may not be sensible.

Any reccommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try placement new and mmap.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650034/how-to-use-mmap-to-point-to-stl-type][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650034/how-to-use-mmap-to-point-to-stl-type

Answer (score 1):

The simple C++ approach is good if there are no plans to enhance the functionality in the future. A middle land that might well suit your needs are key-value stores such as [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/). They handle the storing and interrupts transparently as well as enhancing the storage to multiple machines if one becomes insufficient. Their performance is very good, in some cases they might even outperform the C++ code. A full blown SQL database will be too slow for your purposes unless you run it on several machines.

Answer (score 1):

Use the best hammer for the nail, despite the fact you are most comfortable with your c++ hammer (I'd be in the same boat.)

It sounds like a database is going to be your best bet in terms of performance and data integrity. They are built to handle the kind of scenarios you describe in your post.

The two things I see you needing to do, then, are:

- Develop a solid database model for the kind of information you are looking to store. I'm no expert in this but I do know getting this right is important.
- Do some research on a good C++ database wrapper. That way you can leave the MySQL details to the library and you can focus on where you are strongest.

Answer (score 0):

If there are millions of stores to the map per second, an SQL that is fast enough becomes quite involved for something that you seem to be conceiving as an afterthought.  A keystore might be better for your app, but if you are really hitting the limits of performance you might consider just writing out a log of the updates you make to your in-memory store.  You could reconstruct the in-memory store from the log to satisfy your persistance requirement.

Comment: Does the performance equation change if there are less frequent stores (100s or 1000s per second) but still millions of loads per second?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use your map, wrapped in an object handling operations on the map.
Operations which modify the map would besides modifying the map in memory, also update the on-disk-storage.

Then your next problem would be to identify what storage model is most suited to your data, e.g. an sql database, or maybe a log noting all updates, or maybe a binary file with fixed sized records and your own indexing scheme.

If there is also a requirement that the database can be shared between several users, each possibly updating it, then you would also need to add a mechanism to keep your map in sync. ... maybe by then it would become easier to just always query.  But in any case by then you have your object handling all operations on the data, and would only need to replace the internals of that object.

Comment: Thanks - I guess that would give me the speed of the map, with the database as a backup behind it

Answer (score 0):

I am not a user of your application but storing large amounts of data as you close is a bad idea for multiple reasons:

- When someone wants to close down your application they want it to close fairly swiftly, not hang around for ages. If it doesn't go down they are likely to kill it.
- If they "crash out" your data will not have been saved.

Periodic saves are therefore a much better idea, and for this you would probably want to mark rows as "dirty" when they are currently unsaved which means you might want more data to mark dirty records. This could be done with a straightforward set or vector of keys for which the data is dirty, and periodically save them and remove their dirty status.

On closing you would write any remaining dirty records but there will not be a lot of them.

A lot of this does depend on how frequently your maps change.

Remember also that user interaction should always have the highest priority and any committing of your "dirty" members to persistence should happen in a background thread with low priority.